# Optimization strategy for "get most recent comments from all posts"

Tags: mysql

The goal of this query is to get the most recent comments that others users have made on someone's post. It should have the name of the user who commented, the title of the post they commented on, and the actual comment text.

There are three tables, MySQL myisam:

```
comment: id, author_fk, post_fk, text, date, ...
post: id, author_fk, content, date, ...
user: id, name, ...
```

This is how I'm getting the most recent comments made by people on a user's posts:

```
SELECT comment.text, user.name, post.title 
FROM comments
JOIN user ON user.id = comment.author_fk
JOIN post ON post.id = comment.post_fk
WHERE post.author_fk = [id of the user who posted content] 
ORDER BY comment.id
LIMIT 20
```

Here is a thread I've referenced when doing this: [mysql/php: show posts and for each post all comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254361/mysql-php-show-posts-and-for-each-post-all-comments)

The problem is that this is really slow. I'm working with a database that has over 2million posts, 15million comments, and about 500thousand users. What kind of indexing strategy should be applied? Is there a better way to write the query? Is it possible to get the query to return the results in a matter of seconds? It seems that how slow or fast this is is depending on the number of posts a user has.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You know, when you get to that kind of size it's OK to get some professional support.

Comment: @SamD It's an AWS db.m1.small RDS instance: 1.7 GB memory, 1 ECU (1 virtual core with 1 ECU), 64-bit platform, moderate I/O capacity. All the tables are using myisam.

Comment: What happens if you specify `INNER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`?  That should speed it up at least a bit.  Also, what indexes do you currently have on these three tables?  And when did you last analyze the tables?

Comment: @user3124219 1.7 GB is too little for that much data upgrade your hardware, run explain on the query to make sure it uses indexes

Comment: @dg99: the inclusion of the `INNER` keyword doesn't impact performance in MySQL. The MySQL parser interprets `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` exactly like `JOIN`.

Comment: Please provide the output from `EXPLAIN ...` and the create table statements for the 3 tables that you reference.

Comment: @dg99 Explicitly using INNER JOIN is not making a difference. My indexing should be fine from what I'm seeing in EXPLAIN, but there is one for post.author_fk, comment.author_fk, comment.post_fk, (comment.post_fk, comment.author_fk), user.id. Maybe you could share your thoughts on how you would index this? The table is analyzed regularly, so it's ok there

Comment: @SamD Hm. I will see how this performs on a larger instance: Large DB instance: 7.5 GB memory, 4 ECUs (2 virtual cores with 2 ECUs each), 64-bit platform, high I/O capacity

Comment: @user3124219  if you also switch to innodb and change the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5 GB on the new instance you'll see a huge performance gain

Answer (score 0):

**FOLLOWUP**

I noticed the comments added by OP 2 months after the question.  I'll resist reiterating the points I made in my original answer (preserved below), such as using `EXPLAIN` , creating appropriate covering indexes, and adding predicates to the query. Given that the OP has verified that.

An InnoDB buffer pool that is "too small" is going to cause performance issues, especially if there are concurrent queries competing for blocks in the pool, and causing disk reads. (As I noted earlier, "Using filesort" operations can be expensive (in terms of resources and time.)

Given the significant volume of rows, and the performance requirement, I'd be aiming for an query plan that accessed a single index, and avoided a "Using filesort" operation.

At this point, I'd be looking to denormalize the data model for performance, so that I could have an appropriate index.

Given that there's an equality predicate on `post.author_fk`, and (effectively) a descending range scan on `comment.id`, I'd be looking at getting these two columns into a single index.

And that means I'd be adding the value of `post.author_fk` as a column in the `comments` table.

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD post_author ...
```

Of course, the code that does INSERT/UPDATE to the `comments` table will need to be modified, to maintain this column. (Getting the entire table updated would be painful, given the number of rows, I wouldn't attempt that in a one fell swoop. If I had to do that, I'd tackle that in smaller bunches.

Next, I'd add an index on that table:

```
CREATE INDEX comments_IX2 ON comments (post_author, id)
```

Then, I'd get a query that used that as a covering index, and get that LIMIT 20 applied as soon as possible. We are very cautious introducing inline views (since they can be performance killers), but in this case, given a limit of 20 rows, I'd start with a query that can quickly get just the rows from comments that are of interest, using an index scan.

```
   SELECT c.id
        , c.post_fk
        , c.author_fk
        , c.text
     FROM comments c
    WHERE c.post_author = [id of the user who posted content]
    ORDER BY c.post_author DESC, c.id DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

That query should be able to avoid a "Using filesort" operation, by making use of a descending range scan on the new index.  Ideally, we'd have a covering index, but given that we need to return the `text` column, maintaining a larger index would likely be more expensive. One I verified that this query performs well, I'd wrap that in parens, and include that as an inline view, in another query, like:

```
SELECT c.text
     , u.name
     , p.title 
  FROM ( SELECT c.id                                                 
              , c.post_fk
              , c.author_fk
              , c.text
           FROM comments c
          WHERE c.post_author = [id of the user who posted content]  -- new col 
          ORDER BY c.post_author DESC, c.id DESC                     -- new col
          LIMIT 20
       ) t
  JOIN user u
    ON u.id = t.author_fk
  JOIN post p
    ON p.id = t.post_fk
 ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**  If the query is returning the results you want

(I suspect you mean to `ORDER BY comment.id DESC`, assuming that the id column is AUTO_INCREMENT, or similar ascending value where the latest comments have a "higher" id value.)

Here's how I'd go about making adjustments to the indexes and query plan.

First, and foremost, use an EXPLAIN to get the query plan MySQL is currently using.

Second, verify that statistics are up to date... use an `ANALYZE TABLE` on each table.

Looking at the query, it looks like we'd definitely want some indexes. We want an index with on the `post` table with `author_fk` as the leading column, since there's an equality predicate, and we'd expect some pretty good cardinality (we expect this predicate will usually eliminate a good number of rows, and return fewer than 10% of the rows.

(If this was InnoDB, and this was defined as a FOREIGN KEY constraint, then an appropriate index would already exist).  If the rows in post are fairly "large", and the "title" column is usually fairly small, then I'd be inclined to include that column in the index as well, so that we'd have a covering index.  (The EXPLAIN output will show "`'Using index'`" in the `Extra` column when the query is being satisfied from the index without referencing pages in the underlying table, and that can speed up performance significantly.)

Since the query also references the `id` column, that may also need to be included, although, if that's the PRIMARY KEY (cluster key), that column value may actually already be included in the index, as the "pointer" back to the row in the table.

```
... ON post (author_fk, title, id)
```

Since the predicate for the join to the `comment` table is on the `post_fk` column, we'd likely want 
an index with that column leading. It may be beneficial to create a covering index for this table as well, though that may not benefit performance much, if the `text` column occupies the vast majority of space in the comment table.

```
... ON comment (post_fk)
```

I think the biggest performance killer in your query plan is going to be the sort operation. (The EXPLAIN output will likely show `'Using filesort'` in the `Extra` column.)

MySQL is going to have to retreive every row from the `comment` table that satisfies the predicate, and then  perform a sort operation on that set of rows.

If you could add some other predicate, like you don't want comments with a date over 7 days ago, or soemthing like that, that would cut down the number of rows that need to be sorted.

That LIMIT clause gets applied nearly last in the query plan. So, even though you are asking for only 20 rows, MySQL may actually be sorting thousands and thousands of rows.

The join predicate to the `user` table is already on what looks to be a the primary key.

(I'm assuming the normative pattern that `id` column is defined as the PRIMARY KEY of each table.)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply and sorry for responding so late. After digging into it, indeed, it is the sorting that is causing all this pain. I have all the indexes you suggested and the query is very fast when I remove the "ORDER BY comment.id DESC" but I can't find a way to sort and have the query be fast. Unfortunately, I can't do the sorting and limiting with PHP as it would eat up way too much RAM in case 10s of thousands of rows are returned...

Comment: I've read that the ORDER BY uses a 'filesort' and 'temporary' when there isn't an index on what you're ordering by. Why then, when I'm ordering by the primary index comment.id is it having to use the 'filesort/temporary'? I'm guessing it's related to the joining happening here....

Comment: I tried adding a date predicate as you suggested. It improves the query time by quite a bit, but it's still too slow. To give you an idea, running this without the date clause can take 30+ seconds when this query has to sort through 15k plus rows (that is, a user has had 15k+ comments added to his posts). Limiting this to comments added within the last week reduces the execution time between 10 and 20 seconds, give or take. It's better, but not acceptable if hundreds of users are accessing this query.